# How to remotely toggle application features?

Tags: android, ads

I want to test two ad agencies on my application. I know there are some ad companies that merge all these companies together but that's not what I'm looking for.  I want to be able to control application features remotely.  Is there a service such as flurry or such that gives the option to change settings remotely? Or do I have to implement my own? This feature is strictly for developer use and not the actual application users.

Hopefully what I'm asking is understandable...

Thanks!

-Jona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out [www.adwhirl.com](http://www.adwhirl.com)
.I'm using it and it's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to implement your own solution.

Make your apps communicate with a server on startup and read settings from there.
Also, Android supports push notifications from the 'cloud'. Maybe something to consider.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  Yes, I'm afraid implementing my own would have to do... Thanks...